Credit Index Options and SABR calibration for smile
I was wondering if it made any theoritical sense to use SABR on credit index options, as we can get implied volatilities from quotes (in Bloomberg or by inversion of Black model). I get that the SABR model is usually on Swaptions or Caps/Floors and that it probably was not made to be used on credit products, as there is no credit risk in the model, but since it is a forward rate model, I would think that it would still make some sense. Also is there any particular paper on the matter ? How does one account of vol smile in credit index options, especially relating to delta and vega ?
